# How can I write the code to let the User to choose nothing or pick a time?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to write two choice from a `edittext`for the User either enter nothing(which means no need to set the remind date)or pick a time through `datePickerDialog` to remind.How can I implement?

This is my `edittext` addtime's code:

```
addtime.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           datePickerDialog.show();
           return false;
       }
   });
```

Comment: it would be better to use textview ange it background of edittext as a grey box or line and set its innitial text as date and on its click open date picker dialogue

Comment: @ApoorvSingh Can you say it  detailed? Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: So you don't know how to initialize `datePickerDialog` on `EditText`?

Comment: @EJusius Yes, I know .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this edittextunfocused.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<stroke android:color="@color/grey"
    android:width="@dimen/twoDp"/>
<corners android:radius="@dimen/twoDp"></corners>
</shape>
```

and in place of your EditText put this

```
<EditText
 android:layout_width="match_parent"                   
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/edittextunfocused"
 android:text="Add Time"
 android:id="@+id/addtime"

                    />
```